# Mongoose Geo Location is not pass than thrown error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, geolocation

As I tried to insert `polygon` data in mongoose insert successfully If i passed in POST request But, If couldn't pass it's thrown error.

Schema

```
let pSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    number: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type:{
            type: String,
            enum: [
                "Point",
                "MultiPoint",
                "LineString",
                "MultiLineString",
                "Polygon",
                "MultiPolygon"
            ]
        },
        coordinates:{
            type: [[Number]],
            default: [0, 0]
        } 
    }
});
```

Query

```
let newP = new P();
newP.name = req.body.name;
newP.number = req.body.number;
if(req.body.location){  //  location : [[],[],[]]   what if not passed ?
    newP.location = {type : "MultiPoint" , coordinates : req.body.location};
}
```

Error

> message: 'Can\'t extract geo keys:

Comment: No default on `"type"`, which is required for GeoJSON. If you are defaulting `[0,0]` then you should make a default `"Point"` for type. BTW, **NOT** a "query", but an "instance constructor". Completely different thing.

Comment: @Gunjan Patel Have you created index like `db.someNewCollection.createIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})`

Comment: @gypsyCoder No I don't create